# Find all solutions for f(x) (without induction)

Tags: functions

$f(x) = 2f(x-1)+1$
$f(1)=1$
find all solutions for $f$ (**spoiler**: there is only one)
**prove it's the only solution** without induction, and show your way to get to the solution.

Comment: Hello, what have you tried already?

Comment: Basically nothing really important

Comment: Try computing $f(2),f(3),f(4),f(5)$ do you see a pattern perhaps?

Comment: I assume that $f$ is only defined on the natural numbers, yes?

Answer (score 1):

$f(2)=2f(1)+1=2\cdot1+1=3$

$f(3)=2f(2)+1=2\cdot3+1=7$

$f(4)=2f(3)+1=2\cdot7+1=15$

$f(5)=2f(4)+1=2\cdot15+1=31$

.
.
.

$f(x)=2^x-1$

Note that $y=a^x$ is a monotonically increasing function of $x$ for all $a \in(0,1)U(1,\infty)$.

So, $f(x)=2^x-1$ is an increasing function of $x$.

The second derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ is: $f''(x)=[\ln(2)]^2\cdot2^x$ which is always positive for all values of $x$, this means that $f$ is always concave-up.

Now to think, is there any other function that is monotonically increasing, concave-up, and satisfying the given definition $f(x)=2f(x-1)+1$? No! (using basic calculus).

$$\boxed{f(x)=2^x-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
f(x)&=2f(x-1)+1\\
f(1)&=1\\
f(2)&=2f(1)+1=3\\
f(3)&=2f(2)+1=7\\
f(4)&=2f(3)+1=15\\
\end{align}

Looks like $f(x)=2^x-1$, as the first differences are the same as the second differences, suggesting an exponential function.

Answer (score 0):

$f(n)=2$ in power of $ n$, minus 1, you can compute it in combinaturical way, its basically the amount of nodes in a recursive tree with 2 sub-trees until the stop condition.
try to imagine rhe recursive tree and than, in every layer i there will be a 2^i nodes

Comment: It's clear the answer is not $f(n)=2^{n+1}$.  That doesn't even work for $n=1$.  Nor is it $2^n+1$ if that's what you meant to write.

Comment: I had typo, fixed it

Comment: So you think it is $f(n)=2^{n+1}-1$?  But that still doesn't work at $n=1$.  Close, of course.  As the other posted solutions have pointed out, the answer is $2^n-1$.

Comment: Sorry, i'll be more accurate next time